# Apache default vhost

Tags: apache-http-server

So what makes the "default" vhost in apache a wildcard for unconfigured domains? ie. what makes this vhost be loaded over anything else when you try and load a domain that isn't configured, in a web browser? I have a feeling it could just be the lack of ServerName and ServerAlias arguments?

I have just set up a new Apache instance and created a new vhost alongside the default. Even when I specify a ServerName, run a2ensite and reload apache, it still loads the default page from the default vhost.

Answer (score 2):

The default virtual host is the very first one parsed. That's why in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` it usually is put as `000-default`.

You can also check by using `apache2ctl -S`. It explicitly states which virtual host is the default one.

Maybe you have a typo in your configuration? Check the leading `VirtualHost` line for IP and port and check `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` for typos as well.